# Publishing company's reps refusing to send desk copies to my home. Any way around this?

Tags: books, publishers

A certain popular publishing company won't send a textbook to my home, for a course I'm teaching this Fall; It's a new edition for this year. I understand they have policies, but I was expecting some kind of favor during the COVID business. It isn't easy to get the textbook if it's shipped to the campus right now, because the college is completely locked down. Has anyone found ways to convince publishers to send them out to home addresses?

Comment: Would "OK, I'll just use a free online textbook for my 100-student class instead." work?

Comment: @Buffy I don't think that's how it works?

Comment: @DavidPeterson Oh yes it works like that and you have, or the librarian or equivalent, gives them advance notice of numbers - they don’t print overnight for you. It is easier with e-books but many students don’t like those...

Comment: @Buffy Our department has been using their texts for probably 30 years. They have no problem sending "free" desk copies (instructor versions) to me at the college address.

Comment: If the "instructor version" is different from the student version, there may be an issue about where they can be sent. Can someone claim to be a prof and ask for a desk copy?

Comment: @Buffy To Clarify: I am teaching the course in the Fall and need a single desk copy to acclimate myself with the new edition so I can build my syllabus. The online version they supply is substandard, and I prefer a hard copy anyway. Edit: they have  validated me as a faculty member and I have access to the virtual instructor's edition.

Answer (score 6):

Just say “thanks for your help, and mention an equivalent from a different publisher”... also drop in how many copies you would need :)... they need sales and work hard to get them.

Also consider contacting their boss by email, saying you wanted to consider their book but you crossed them off as you can’t inspect the book.

Comment: Thank you. Our department kind of picked out texts in mini committees long ago. I'd like to avoid a confrontational approach but will keep in mind.

Comment: The publisher doesn't need to know that, though.